# How to make string from array?

Tags: arrays, swift, string

I would like to ask you how I can make String from array so that it works for both cases below:

```
var interCity = "IC"
var icLetters = Array(interCity)
var ic = icLetters.joined(separator: "") // No exact matches in call to instance method 'joined'

var trainLetters = ["E", "C"]
var ec = trainLetters.joined(separator: "")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@HangarRash nailed the reason that `joined(separator:)` doesn't work in the first case -- when you construct an Array from a String you get an array of Characters.

Another way to get to the same place is to use `reduce(_ initalResult:, nextPartialResult:)` like this:

```
var interCity = "IC"
var icLetters = Array(interCity)
var ic = icLetters.reduce("") { $0 + String($1) } // returns "IC\n"
```

To do the same in the second case, just omit the `String` constructor since you already have Strings:

```
var trainLetters = ["E", "C"]
var ec = trainLetters.reduce("") { $0 + $1 }.     // returns "EC\n"
```

Answer (score 2):

`icLetters` is `[Character]`, not `[String]` which is why `joined(separator:)` isn't valid.

One way to convert `interCity` into an array of `String` is to do:

```
var icLetters = Array(interCity).map { String($0) }
```

Then you can use `joined(separator: "")`.

Comment: This is pointless. Why not just `String(icLetters)`

Comment: @LeoDabus Better yet, why not just stick with the original `interCity` string? I'm just answering the OP's question. You should post your comment to the question, not my answer.

Comment: Anyway he is not using any separator. Btw empty string is the default value OP can just use `joined()`